# How to properly deploy to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7

Right now I deploy the project to our production server using Visual Studio 10's ftp uploader. It's very slow and I notice it doesn't remove deleted files (ie files deleted in the project) from the server once finished.

How can I make this step more robust, automated and professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at WebDeploy. Scott Hanselman did a great demo of it at PDC and you can watch it here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

It's very robust and extensible.